# How can I convert an array assigment in for loop from C to macro?

Tags: excel, vba

What will be the macro for the below mentioned code in c?

Code:

```
max  = 0.04/x;
arr[0] = y;
for(i = max; i > 0; i-- )
 {
  arr[i] = arr[i-1]; 
  printf(arr[i],%d);
 }
```

I wrote the below mentioned macro but its throwing me run time error: '9'

```
Sub forloop()

 Dim arr() As Long
 Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
 ReDim Preserve arr(i)

 arr(0) = Cell.Value(2,B)
 For i = Cell.value(1,A) To 2 Step -1
   arr(i) = arr(i-1)

 Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: `I wrote the below macro` - what language is that?

Comment: macro as in VBA for excel

Comment: How is VBA and excel related to embedded?

Comment: Edited your tags.

Comment: @KamilCuk. Thats a long story. needed for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `Cells` and `Value` round the wrong way

```
Sub forloop()
    Dim arr() As Long
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
    ReDim Preserve arr(i)

    arr(0) = Cells(2,"B").Value2

    For i = Cells(1,"A").Value2 To 2 Step -1
        arr(i) = arr(i-1)
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `For i = Cells(1,"A").Value2 To 1 Step -1`?

Comment: BTW `ReDim Preserve arr(i)` can be simply `ReDim arr(i)`

Comment: When I run the macro it throws the runtime error '9'

Comment: I made the change ReDim Preserve arr(40). It works like charm now